# Issue with RMSE calculation in Shiny app using observation and simulation data

Tags: r, shiny

I have been working on a Shiny app to evaluate climatic data using observation and simulation datasets. The app is designed to load two files: one for observation data and another for simulation data. The observation data file contains columns for year, month, day, precipitation (RR), maximum temperature (Tmax), and minimum temperature (Tmin). The simulation data file has the same columns.

The primary goal of the app is to calculate the Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) for the precipitation variable (RR) between the observation and simulation datasets while ignoring missing values. However, when running the app and performing the RMSE calculation, the result is returning "NaN" instead of a valid RMSE value.

Issues Encountered:

RMSE returns "NaN": The calculated RMSE for the precipitation variable is resulting in "NaN" (Not a Number) instead of a valid value. I have tried inspecting the data and using the complete.cases function to remove missing values, but the issue persists.

Data format: I have ensured that the data files are read correctly without headers and with appropriate separators. The dates are converted to Date objects using as.Date, and the data seems to be loaded as expected.

Data alignment: I suspect that there might be an issue with data alignment between the observation and simulation datasets, causing incorrect RMSE calculations.

Code Snippet:

I am using the complete.cases function to filter out missing values, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(lubridate)

# Define the UI
# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
                titlePanel("Outil d'évaluation des données climatiques"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    h3("Chargement des données"),
                    fileInput("simul", "Sélectionnez le fichier pour les réanalyses ou les simulations:"),
                    fileInput("obs", "Sélectionnez le fichier pour l'observation:"),
                    actionButton("submitBtn", "Soumettre")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    h4("Contrôle de qualité des données"),
                    tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel("Qualité des données",
                               fluidRow(
                                 column(width = 5, tableOutput("obsout")),
                                 column(width = 5, tableOutput("simulout"))
                               )
                      ),
                      tabPanel("RMSE Output",
                               verbatimTextOutput("rmse_output")
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
)


# Define the server
server <- function(input, output) {
  NA_percentage <- function(input_vector) {
    missing_values <- is.na(input_vector)
    percentage_missing <- sum(missing_values) / length(input_vector) * 100
    
    result <- list(percentage_missing, missing_values)
    
    return(result)
  }
  
  process_OBS <- function(filename) {
    data1 <- read.table(filename, header = FALSE)
    dates_data <- as.Date(paste(data1$V1, data1$V2, data1$V3, sep = "-"))
    
    min_dat <- min(dates_data)
    max_dat <- max(dates_data)
    dates_data1 <- seq(from = min_dat, to = max_dat, by = "day")
    
    RR_data1 <- data1$V4
    Tmax_data1 <- data1$V5
    Tmin_data1 <- data1$V6
    
    # Data 1: Percentage of missing values and corresponding dates for each parameter
    percentage_missing_RR_data1 <- NA_percentage(RR_data1)[[1]]
    percentage_missing_Tmax_data1 <- NA_percentage(Tmax_data1)[[1]]
    percentage_missing_Tmin_data1 <- NA_percentage(Tmin_data1)[[1]]
    
    missing_dates_RR_data1 <- dates_data1[NA_percentage(RR_data1)[[2]]]
    missing_dates_Tmax_data1 <- dates_data1[NA_percentage(Tmax_data1)[[2]]]
    missing_dates_Tmin_data1 <- dates_data1[NA_percentage(Tmin_data1)[[2]]]
    
    # Prepare the result to return
    result <- data.frame(
      parameter = c("RR", "Tmax", "Tmin"),
      percentage = c(percentage_missing_RR_data1, percentage_missing_Tmax_data1, percentage_missing_Tmin_data1),
      corresponding_day = I(list(paste(missing_dates_RR_data1, collapse = ", "), 
                                 paste(missing_dates_Tmax_data1, collapse = ", "),
                                 paste(missing_dates_Tmin_data1, collapse = ", "))))
    
    return(result)
  }
  
  fill_missing_dates <- function(data) {
    # Convert year, month, and day columns to Date object
    cc <- as.Date(paste(data$V1, data$V2, data$V3, sep = "-"))
    new_data=data.frame(Date=cc,RR=data$V4,Tmax=data$V5,Tmin=data$V6)
    # Step 1: Create a full date vector
    v1_dates <- cc
    min_date <- min(v1_dates)
    max_date <- max(v1_dates)
    full_date_vector <- seq(from = min_date, to = max_date, by = "day")
    
    # Step 2: Find the missing dates
    missing_dates <- full_date_vector[!(full_date_vector %in% v1_dates)]
    
    # Step 3: Replace corresponding values with NA for missing dates
    
    missing_data <- data.frame(Date = missing_dates,
                               par1 = rep(NA, length(missing_dates)),
                               par2 = rep(NA, length(missing_dates)),
                               par3 = rep(NA, length(missing_dates)))
    
    data <- merge(new_data, missing_data, all = TRUE)
    
    # Sort the data by Date
    data <- data[order(data$Date), ]
    dt1=data[,1:4]
    return(data[,1:4])
  }
  
  obs_format <- function(data){
    cc <- as.Date(paste(data$V1, data$V2, data$V3, sep = "-"))
    new_data <- data.frame(Date = cc, RR = data$V4, Tmax = data$V5, Tmin = data$V6)
    return(new_data)
  }
  obs_formated <- NULL
  
  observeEvent(input$submitBtn, {
    if (!is.null(input$obs$datapath)) {
      df_obs <- process_OBS(input$obs$datapath)
      output$obsout <- renderTable(df_obs)
    }
    
    if (!is.null(input$simul$datapath)) {
      data1 <- read.table(input$simul$datapath, header = FALSE)
      df_simul <- fill_missing_dates(data1)
      #to display the date correctly
      df_simul$Date <- format(df_simul$Date, '%Y-%m-%d')
      output$simulout <- renderTable({
        #to display only the added dates in the simulation
        subset(df_simul, is.na(RR) | is.na(Tmax) | is.na(Tmin))
      })
    }
    
    # Calculate the RMSE of RR between df_simul and df_obs while ignoring NA dates
    if (!is.null(df_obs)) {
      # Formating obs to be like simul (date RR tmax Tmin)
      obs_formated <- obs_format(df_obs)
      
      # Filter out NA values from df_simul and df_obs RR vectors
      complete_cases <- complete.cases(obs_formated$RR, df_simul$RR)
      simul_complete <- df_simul$RR[complete_cases]
      obs_complete <- obs_formated$RR[complete_cases]
      
       #Calculate RMSE
      rmse_rr <- sqrt(mean((simul_complete - obs_complete)^2))
      
      # Render the RMSE values in the UI
      output$rmse_output <- renderPrint({
        paste("RMSE of RR:", rmse_rr)
      })
    }
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Sample Data: formated as following
year mounth day RR Tmax Tmin

Observation data:

```
2023 1 1 4 45 46
2023 1 2 6 30 22
2023 1 3 5 23 13
2023 1 4 1 22 26
2023 1 5 8 24 56
2023 1 6 6 4 21
2023 1 7 1 22 26
2023 1 8 8 24 56
2023 1 9 6 4 21
2023 1 10 9 13 48
```

Simulation data:

```
2023 1 1 0 40 42
2023 1 2 0 40 25
2023 1 3 2 56 23
2023 1 6 5 65 65
2023 1 7 1 2 5
2023 1 10 5 6 2
```

Expected Outcome:

I expect the RMSE calculation to return a valid RMSE value for the precipitation variable (RR) between the observation and simulation datasets while ignoring the NA values. Additionally, the observation and simulation tables should display correctly, with missing values appropriately filtered out.

Comment: I think your problem is due to `process_OBS()` changing the format of `df_ob`, so later on, when you call `obs_format()` the result doesn't make sense. I think you should call `obs_format()` on the raw observation data.